# PostgreSQL joined tables with null condition variable

Tags: java, postgresql

I've a problem with my sql query in PostgreSQL while I'm trying to join a lot of tables.
In section 'WHERE' I've a few conditions where I'm comparing some id values, e.g.

```
operator.agent_id = app.operator_id;
```

When every id has no null value, everything works, but in case even one id equals null, when query result is empty.
Can I obtain such a result, that if one id equals null, then only values from this table are null, but rest is correct ?

To be more specific, I'm programming in Java, using EJB3:

```
stringQuery = "SELECT .... FROM ... WHERE...";
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(stringQuery);
List<Object[]> objects = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: reading the question again I'm not entierly sure what you are asking... "that if one id equals null, then only values from this table are null, but rest is correct ?"

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    app
LEFT JOIN
        operator
ON      operator.agent_id = app.operator_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Move it to your join (left join) having the condition in your WHERE clause causes an inner join.